# What's the correct way to work with bounded arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to understand how *bounded* arrays work in C++. I need to have a quick length method to return the size of my bounded array. In Java I would do something like that:

```
int[] array = new int[10];

System.out.println(array.length); // 10
System.out.println(array[5]); // 0

array[5] = 11;

System.out.prinltn(array[5]); // 11
```

If possible I would like to use an *object array* (i.e. a class implementing an array functionality) instead of *pointers*. Would I be correct to say that it feels much more natural to use an object array instead of a memory pointer to work with arrays?

Comment: Of course I googled before posting here.

Comment: `Would I be correct to say the it feels much more natural to use an object array instead of a memory pointer to work with arrays?` what?

Comment: @redFIVE Let me draw it for you, one second.

Comment: `std::vector<>::size()` for dynamic arrays, `std::array<>::size()` for fixed arrays. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is he never bothered to check the documentation. As I said originally, google man, use it. Also, you need to go back and learn how pointers work in c++. An "object array" would just be an array of pointers to locations in memory, so saying `use an object array instead of a memory pointer to work with arrays?` doesn't really make any sense

Comment: @redFIVE, if you wanna look cool, say 'Alphabet, man'.

Comment: @WhozCraig, would you explain the joke to me, please? I feel like I am missing something hillarious, but not getting it :( Not being natural born speaker does this to you.

Comment: @SergeyA, he is saying that he would rather go to mcdonalds than write code for someone who wont even google

Comment: @SergeyA [Yum =P](http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/food/product_nutrition.breakfast.3958.egg-white-delight.html).

Comment: @WhozCraig damn that looks good, we don't have those in canada

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks. By all gods, what happened to yolks and real bacon? I hate this fat-free arrangements. By the way, do you know FDA finally admitted they were in the wrong all this time, and fat-free diet is very unhealthy?

Comment: @redFIVE, yet it is **candian** bacon... How unfair.

Comment: Google for egg McMuffin

Comment: Google for how to get an primitive array size

Comment: Are you sure it's C++?

Comment: @SergeyA It was delicious, btw. Oh the irony that a breakfast sandwich with Canadian bacon is not available in Canada. <facepalm> =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has a class `std::array<type, size>` which is basically just a wrapper for stack-allocated arrays. C++ also has a class `std::vector<type>` which is a wrapper for heap-allocated arrays (like what you're used to in Java) but which also has `ArrayList`-like functionality.

In your case, writing code which is logically and semantically identical to yours is:

```
std::vector<int> array(10, 0); //EDIT: I added the second parameter because I don't think all implementations zero the memory when allocating it. This ensures that the memory is zeroed before use, like it would be in Java.
std::cout << array.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << array[5] << std::endl;
array[5] = 11;
std::cout << array[5] << std::endl;
```

Though, I wouldn't name the variable `array`, since that could be confusing.

Comment: @JacobsWright That's not quite true. `vector` objects in c++ can have arbitrary lengths, but the lengths are still runtime-defined, like in Java. If you were to access `array[11]` in the code I provided, you'd get errors, because when I initialized the object, I specified a length of 10.

Comment: I thought vector was like a Java vector. It can grow as you add more elements.

Comment: It looks like if I place this array object in the heap through *new* I cannot do `array[5]` anymore. I have to do `array->at(5)`. Is that correct?

Comment: @JacobsWright You're writing the code wrongly, then. Write it exactly the way I wrote it, and don't use the keyword `new`. If you're new to c++, you should never, *ever* be using the keywords `new` or `delete`. If you think you need to, then you're either an advanced user (which isn't the case based on the code snippets provided here) or you haven't learned the c++ basics yet.

Comment: I'm going to be passing this int array around, it will be stored in a hash map, so it needs to be in the heap, not in the stack. The Java code I wrote put this on the heap. Your code put it on the stack.

Comment: @JacobsWright If you assign an entry of a map to a vector, the vector's contents will be copied into the map. There's still no reason to be using raw pointers unless the vector contains objects which are expensive to copy, which isn't the case if it's a byte array. If you include those broader considerations into your original problem prompt, I'll update my answer to address them.

Comment: Let's say my int array has 128k elements. Do I have to copy all elements to the the vector inside my map? I would prefer to store a pointer to the vector inside my map, no?

Comment: @JacobsWright First of all, that's only 512 Kilobytes, so yes, copying would still be preferable to the design nightmares that arise when handling raw pointers. Especially because if you design your code correctly, it'll become a move operation, rather than a copy, which would make it identical to your solution in performance. Secondly, if the copy issue really is substantial, then a better solution is to grab a *reference* to the vector that already exists in the map and to perform operations (like adding data) on that, rather than creating a new one and copying it (or its pointer) in.

Comment: Thanks, man. I believe the contents of a vector are in the heap anyways, so they will not be copied (shallow copy)?

Comment: @JacobsWright Like I said, it depends on how you design your code. A good programmer will organize things so that the vector you put in your map can be "moved" (using c++ move semantics), and therefore the cost of copying the vector over is as simple as copying the heap reference, plus a few implementation-defined "bookkeeping" variables. If not, then the contents would indeed have to be copied, but the good news there is that `memcpy` is quite cheap, relatively speaking.